# When moving to another page and coming back to the page where slick carousel is present, slick carousel is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

_high.html.erb:

```
<div class="col-xl-12">
  <div class="default-slick-carousel freelancers-container freelancers-grid-layout">
    <%= render partial: '/pages/top_trainers' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

##To reinitialize the carousel when coming back to the carousel page, I have added this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.default-slick-carousel').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
      infinite: false,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: false,
      arrows: true,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1292,
          settings: {
            dots: true,
            arrows: false
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 993,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
            dots: true,
            arrows: false
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 769,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            dots: true,
            arrows: false
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  })
</script>
```

So, when I am on this page, carousel is working fine.But when i am moving to some other page and coming back to the carousel page, carousel sliding is not working

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" is there an error in the console?

Comment: Are you using turbolinks on your page?

Comment: No I am not using turbo links @pduersteler

Comment: @Spangle
I mean carousel can slide to left and right, say if there are 5 items, it shows up 3 and then I can slide to see the rest. This does not work when coming back to the page.And there is no error in the console